# How to compile just one file in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In VC++ I can press CTRL+F7 to compile a single file, or right click on a source file ot compile it.
Is it possible to compile a single file (or current file) in C#?

I would like to for example know if my current file has any errors in it without having to compile everything.

Comment: The C# compiler is *incredibly* fast at compiling a single assembly, even one with a serious amount of code in.   Are you sure you actually being held up by this?

Comment: Agree, absolutely annoying behavior because errors on other files are distracting, specially when you are full focused in solving a specific problem in the current file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it is not possible to do this in C#.

Unlike C++ a C# file cannot be reasonably compiled on it's own to determine if it has any errors.  C++ achieves this through `#include` statements which allows a .cpp file to understand the declaration of types available.  These declarations define the structure of types the current file depends on and allows the compiler to ensure they are used according to specification.

This process is handled implicitly in C#.  The set of declarations available is simply the set of all declarations in all compiled files which are otherwise accessible.  There is no way to forward declare dependencies in the manner C++ does and hence no way to ensure they are being used correctly within a single file.

Comment: Couldn't it in theory though parse everything it needs and ignore all errors except the ones of types used in my current source file?  So it only reports the ones needed.

Comment: @Winforms, why not just compile and sort the error list by file name and scroll to the file in question?

Comment: I guess, when in the middle of refactoring a large peice of code though I'd like to only see errors for that file, but I see your point.  Just one of my annoyances since moving to C#

Comment: You can compile a single file using the Visual studio CLI. I created a single c# file (hello.cs), navigated to the directory it is saved, ran the command csc hello.cs. An exe was created

Comment: Yes, it can be done. A compiler's original job is actually to compile 1 single source file into the target i.e. in this case the .cs file to it's IL file. See @dicentiu's answer for further steps.

Answer (score 14):

For single .cs file compile + run:

1. In VS 2008, go to "Tools" > "External Tools"
2. Click on "Add"
3. Title: Run CSC (or whatever you want)
4. Command: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
5. Arguments: /c C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe /target:winexe $(ItemPath)  && $(ItemFileName)
6. Initial directory: $(ItemDir)
7. Check Use Output Window
8. Apply + Ok
9. Go to Tools and choose "Run CSC"

If this doesn't work, verify that your paths for `cmd` and `csc` match.

Comment: Excellent work.
In addition, if you are using Visual Studio 2010, replace **v3.5** with **v4.0.30319** in step 5.

Comment: The CSC.exe is the C-Sharp Compiler. This can be invoked from command prompt as well and the same can be achieved.

Answer (score 3):

A Visual Studio add-in tool like ReSharper is a very good investment for this situation.

ReSharper performs continuous background solution-wide code analysis and will report issues by conveniently displaying a bar next to your code file\document scrollbar which has red\orange lines denoting any lines of code that have issues\errors. The displayed lines are click-able to navigate to the line in question and also have tool-tips detailing what the exact problem is:

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html#Continuous_Code_Quality_Analysis

```
           http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/screenshots/50/marker_bar.png
```

The issues\warnings that ReSharper can check for are configurable (but it has excellent configuration out-of-the-box), and can denote anything from errors which would cause the code not to compile to more subtle issues where it has detected a possible null method call result which has not been explicitly checked for.

Answer (score 1):

In command line:
%windir%\Microsoft.Net\framework\V3.5\csc.exe /target:library File.cs

You could reasonably attach this to the solution explorers context menu through Tools->External Tools

set the arguments to /target:library $(ItemPath)

something like that might do what you want. Though the file would have to depend on no other files in the project or in referenced binaries aside from what's in the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

Shift-F6 will compile the current assembly, which is *almost* what you want.

Comment: Which version of VS is this? I tried Shift+F6 and nothing happened.

Comment: That was probably 2008 given that it was posted in 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. You can call the compiler directly using command prompt. i.e.

1. Create single file 'hello.cs'
2. Open the Visual Studio command prompt
3. Navigate to the directory that has 'hello.cs'
4. Run `csc hello.cs`
5. Execute your single file by typing `hello.exe`

This will at least tell you whether a single file compiles or not. You can find more information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done using the [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/) .NET Framework. At the command prompt, run `mcs path/to/file.cs`.

From the [Mono docs](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/):

> To compile, use csc:
>
> ```
> csc hello.cs
> ```
>
> Note: csc compiler is not available on all platforms or in very old Mono versions, in such cases use mcs instead.
>
> The compiler will create “hello.exe”, which you can run using:
>
> ```
> mono hello.exe
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio 2022 csc.exe

navigate here in PowerShell:

PS C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Msbuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn

compile single file into dll or exe:

.\csc.exe -target:library -out:"C:\Users\quick\OneDrive\Desktop\C#\PerpetualCalendar\PerpetualCalendar.dll" "C:\Users\quick\OneDrive\Desktop\C#\PerpetualCalendar\PerpetualCalendar.cs"

cs file needs Main Method
.\csc.exe -target:exe -out:"C:\Users\quick\OneDrive\Desktop\C#\PerpetualCalendar\PerpetualCalendar.exe" "C:\Users\quick\OneDrive\Desktop\C#\PerpetualCalendar\PerpetualCalendar.cs"