# How to take input from user in C#?

Tags: c#, methods, input, console-application, user-input

I have the following program.

```
using System;    
public class myeventhandler
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public myeventhandler(int a, int b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }

    public myeventhandler()
    { 
    }

    public int add()
    {
        return x + y; 
    }

    public int sub()
    {
        return x - y;
    }

}

public class test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int a, b;

        Console.WriteLine("enter the first number");
        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("enetr the second no");
        b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        myeventhandler mh = new myeventhandler(a,b);
        int z = mh.add();
        Console.WriteLine("you enetered {0} and {1} whose sum is {}", a, b,z);
        Console.ReadKey();
        //Console.WriteLine("the sum of {0} and {1} is {2}", a, b, mh.add());
        //Console.ReadKey();         
    }
}
```

When I run this program, it stops working after taking both the input. I cannot find what's wrong here.

As shown in the code I believe the value taken from user is first converted to int and then saved to variable a.

If it is so then what's the problem?

Comment: What does "stops working" mean? Be a little more specific.

Comment: My mistake,i missed the number inside {}.

Comment: @user35, don't forget to mark either danielad or Leo as the answer to help out any other users that find this question later on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably getting a `FormatException` because "{}" is not a recognized format. Change that line of code to...

```
Console.WriteLine("you enetered {0} and {1} whose sum is {2}", a, b,z);
```

and you should be fine

Answer (score 1):

When you say it stops working do you mean the application closes and exits or it just hangs there?

The best way to find out what's going in is to debug your code. Assuming your using Visual Studio (any edition) you can put your cursor in the second print line (enter the second no) and press F9 or left click in the margin to make a red dot appear. This is a breakpoint and the debugger will pause when your program gets to this point. Now press F5 to launch the program with the debugger and you'll soon hit your breakpoint.

From the debug window down the bottom you can see the local variables as well as add any that you want to watch. With the F10 and F11 you can step over lines of code and step into methods respectively. By doing this you can verify that a and b are what you think they are. In addition if an exception is thrown because it can't parse the value that was entered from the console, Visual Studio will tell you what the problem is. More often than not this will help you fix the code.

Once you get more knowledgeable about coding you will definitely want to look into Unit Testing and possibly Test Driven Development (TDD) so that you can be sure that your code behaves as expected within a range of conditions.

Comment: I can see the breakpoint but f5 dosen't seen to work.Actually i don't know how to compile a single .cs file in vs10. What i am doing is coding in vs10,saving in folder and compiling via command prompt and the running the .exc file generated.

Comment: @user35 lol is there any not-so-obvious reason why you have such a powerful IDE like VS10 and you prefer to compile using a command prompt?

Comment: @Leo yes it is too obvious, but i don't seem to find any way to compile a single separate independent .cs file. All i know is to compile the .cs file that is inside the project.

Comment: @Leo see this link it says not possible to compile single file in vs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320641/how-to-compile-just-one-file-in-c

Comment: @user35 I never mentioned it was possible...it's just that the use case is soooo scarce that I don't remember when was the last time I needed to compile a single file. Mainly due to the project-solution philosophy in VS I had never needed to compile one single file, compiling one single project in a solution usually suffices

Comment: @Leo so what's your point? I was seeking the way to compile the single file not the whole project.I do know how to compile and test .cs files inside the project. But this is not what we are talking about. Isn't it?