# How could I know the specific command visual studio use to compile a c# solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In property dialog for a single c++ file, I could see the command to compile the the single c++ file. 
[image: c++ property dialog]

But for c# project, I could not even compile a single cs file. Are there any means to know what's the exact command line used in VS to produce the final assembly?

Comment: Did you make a simple Google search? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: I am asking for how to monitor vs rather than simple usage.

Comment: Visual Studio uses MSBuild. The .csproj file is basically an MSBuild project file. Most of the elements in the .csproj file are MSBuild-related via the Target that is fetched in one of the last lines in the .csproj file.

Comment: You can turn on MSBuild logging, and it will show you which parameters it uses when it invokes csc.exe.

Comment: In Visual Studio under Tools - Options - Projects and Solutions - Build and Run, there are two MSBuild verbosity settings. Can't remember where MSBuild places its log files though, sorry.

Comment: Looking at an MSBuild log from building a C# project via msbuild.exe (not interactive Visual Studio) on a .csproj file, and the invocation of csc.exe is an unbelievable 16 kb of parameters!

Comment: @RenniePet Tools - Options - Projects and Solutions - Build and Run -  MSBuild project build log file verbosity may not work for C#, see the last line in this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyhcc7zc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would like to declare is you **are** able to compile a single C# code, but you need to put the code to a separate project, or build it via command line, see here: [How to compile just one file in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320641/how-to-compile-just-one-file-in-c)

For your second question, it seems you are unable to access or modify the command used in VS to compile C# code. However, you could check all your building options via `Property (right click on your project name)->Build`, and specify your customized pre and post building events on `Property->Build Event`.

As the last resort, turn on MSBuild logging to see some building details. You can refer to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb651789.aspx) and [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyhcc7zc.aspx).